# Qemu vs. Xen(Qemu): virsh can't find qemu

Tags: virtualization, qemu, xen

Im running following setup build from source:

```
libvirt
Xen(quemu was part of Xen build process)
```

virsh vol-create qcow2 Responds to me: No qemu installd, only raw possible.
Every solution pointet out for this problem is apt-install the qemu package.

So what happens if I do so? In which way is this conflicting with the already working version of qemu running under Xen?

Is it possible to tell virt/virsh where the qemu(Xen) binaries are placed?

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to install the qhole qemu package. only `qemu-util` is needed. It contains beside some other stuff `qemu-img` which is needed for virsh. Size after installation is 17,3 MB.

I still don't know if this small package influences the Xen system, but time will show. I'll keep this up to date, if there are upcomming problems.